# What should I set COMP_CWORD, COMP_LINE, and COMP_POINT to to get npm completion to work?

Tags: node.js, npm, zsh

```
✗ source <(npm completion)
✗ npm run [press tab]
_bash_complete:8: bad math expression: operator expected at `QIPREFIX +...'
_files:10: bad output format specification
_files:20: bad output format specification
_files:96: bad output format specification
_files:107: bad output format specification
_next_label:9: bad math expression: operator expected at `funcstack ...'
```

From the docs:

> When COMP_CWORD, COMP_LINE, and COMP_POINT are defined in the environment, npm completion acts in "plumbing mode", and outputs completions based on the arguments.

But none of those are set on my system (zshell + oh my zshell on Mac OS X):

```
✗ echo $COMP_CWORD

✗ echo $COMP_LINE 

✗ echo $COMP_POINT
```

What do I need to set them to to get completion working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are bash variables: you're getting the bash completion for npm.

The output of npm completion looks for the existence of the `complete`, `compdef` and `compctl` commands in turn. It must be finding a complete command in your setup, assuming that you use bash and thus enabling the bash completion.

At a guess you probably have `complete` because you've loaded bashcompinit. Perhaps you can delay loading that or perhaps you don't really need it. What completions, if any, do you use it for?